# How to group by current index in a multiple chained groupby-agg in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm currently trying to find a better way to chain multiple groupby-agg operations in pandas. The idea is to reuse the multi-index from a previous groupby-agg, except but one column, to groupby and perform a new aggregation.

Here's a toy example of how I would write spontanously the operations

```
import random
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "name" : random.choices(["N1", "N2", "N3"], k=100),
    "part" : random.choices(["P1", "P2", "P3"], k=100),
    "sub" : random.choices(["S1", "S2", "S3"], k=100),
    "val" : range(100),
})


(
    data
    .groupby(["name", "part", "sub"])
    ["val"]
    .mean()
    .groupby(["name", "part", ])
    .agg(["mean", "std"])
    .groupby(["name",])
    .mean()
)
```

Rather than explicitely referencing the grouping list at each step, I would like to be able to use the current multi-index but one column.
I'm purposely trying to avoid the syntax using `groupby(level=[0, 1])` because I dont think it is much different of writing the actual list.

I'm hoping for a syntax that would allow me to do something like this in pseudo-code :

```
(
    data
    .groupby(["name", "part", "sub"])
    ["val"]
    .mean()
    .groupby(current_index_but('sub'))
    .agg(["mean", "std"])
    .groupby(current_index_but('part'))
    .mean()
)
```

OR

```
(
    data
    .groupby(["name", "part", "sub"])
    ["val"]
    .mean()
    .reset_index("sub")
    .groupby(current_index)
    .agg(["mean", "std"])
    .reset_index("part")
    .groupby(current_index)
    .mean()
)
```

One of my main issue so far is that using a callable inside pd.groupby seems to actually apply the function to each elements of the index. This leaves me unable to do something like this
`groupby(lambda df: df.index.drop("sub"))`

Does anyone has a nice way to work around this issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html)?

```
(
    data
    .groupby(["name", "part", "sub"])
    ["val"]
    .mean()
    .pipe(lambda g: g
        .groupby(g.index.names[:-1])
        .agg(["mean", "std"])
        .pipe(lambda g: g
            .groupby(g.index.names[:-1])
            .mean()
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. I'm waiting just a bit to see if someone comes up with a better one. Thanks

Comment: @AlixTC sure take your time (note that you can always change your mind at any moment after you chose an answer)  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around with the code and [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74743107/14463044) provided by @mozway, and after a bit of refactoring I was able to come up with something that has fewer indentations and has full syntax highlighting in VS code.

The first version is a simple wrapper for the pipe to group by current index:

```
from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy


def groupby_current_index(dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> DataFrameGroupBy:
    return dataframe.groupby(dataframe.index.names)

(
    data
    .groupby(["name", "part", "sub"])
    ["val"]
    .mean()
    .reset_index('sub', drop=True)
    .pipe(groupby_current_index)
    .agg(["mean", "std"])
    .reset_index('part')
    .pipe(groupby_current_index)
    .mean()
)
```

The second brings together the reset index and the groupby while preventing the use of `inplace=True`:

```
def reset_idx_groupby_current_idx(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, *args,
                                  **kwargs) -> DataFrameGroupBy:
    """Reset part of the current index and group by the remainining index.
    Facilitates chaining of groupby-agg methods 
    """
    dataframe = dataframe.reset_index(*args, inplace=False, **kwargs)
    return dataframe.groupby(dataframe.index.names)

(
    data
    .groupby(["name", "part", "sub"])
    ["val"]
    .mean()
    .pipe(reset_idx_groupby_current_idx, "sub", drop=True)
    .agg(["mean", "std"])
    .pipe(reset_idx_groupby_current_idx, "part",)    
    .mean()
)
```

Thanks again @mozway for the help